# `require': File not found zlib.so

Tags: ruby, rubygems, arm, zlib

I've installed ruby and ruby gems on an Arm architecture.
On Arm dns323, the ruby binary works, but when I run the gem binary, I have an error:

> /opt/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/spec_fetcher.rb:1:in `require': File not found - /opt/lib/ruby/1.9.1/arm-linux/zlib.so (LoadError)

The only command that works is:

> gem environment

Of course, zlib.so exists in that folder!

If you have any idea about this problem, help me please!

Comment: did you try installing ruby and rubygems via rvm or rbenv?

Comment: @Pierre did you install zlib-devel from you package and then did a make install after make clean

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the RUBYLIB environment variable. Make sure it includes the directory in which zlib.so is located.
I also run Ruby on ARM, this is what I use:

```
export RUBYLIB=/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/arm-linux-eabi:/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/
```